# How can I round the inner corner of a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I have this shape.
When I add stroke and make the round the corner I still have the inner corners and they are not round.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Looks like your corner radius is too small compared to the thickness of the line. Increase the radius until the inner angles are slightly rounded, or reduce the thickness of the line.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the **Live Corners Widget**, leave the corners at a right angle and try:

- **Menu Effect** > **Stylize** > **Round Corners**

[image: Round Corners]

Answer (score 0):

The Rounded Rectangle tool leaves corners square inside, requiring the clever workarounds above.

But use the plain old Rectangle tool — with SQUARE corners — to make a rectangle. Then use Effect > Stylize > Round corners to set the radius of your corners. The corners will be round inside AND out! Counterintuitive, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it in the following way:

- First set the stroke alignment to "Outside". This will make the stroke stay completely outside your path.
- Now use the filter effect: Fx > Stylize > Round corners. The will make your path (and therefore the stroke) rounded.
- Finally, reduce the size of your path to compensate for the extra thickness outside.